# What happens if void type function returns nothing?

Tags: c++, c

Let's say we have function like this

```
void test() {return;}
```

Is is it correct C code? I just tested it in mingw and compiler says nothing, the same for

```
void test() {return 1;}
```

So I guess I have really outdated compiler.

What should happen in given cases in both C/C++?

**EDIT**:

The `return 1;` gives me a warning. Does this mean `return;` is correct?

Comment: The first is fine, as the function doesn't actually return anything (no expression after `return`). The second should have given a warning though.

Comment: MinGW with gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 warns about the second case.

Comment: You can also just omit the `return;` altogether (and generally should if you've got `return;` at the end of a function).

Comment: In Visual Studio, second line will give an error that Since "test" returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 preview does not allow second variant: `error C2562: 'test' : 'void' function returning a value`

Comment: You're asking what should happen in C and C++ if you write these constructs.  If this is what you want to know, then the answer should be in the language standards.  If you're trying to write good code, then pay attention to the warnings.

Comment: It's not complicated.  You defined a function that you told the compiler would return nothing, and then you returned something.  What do *you* think is going to happen?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Unfortunately, it *is* a bit complicated. Without reading the specific requirements of the language standard (actually *standards*, since the question is tagged both C and C++), how would you know whether the result is a compile-time error, a warning, undefined behavior, discarding the result of the expression, or some combination? The 1990 ISO C standard, for example, does not specifically forbid either a `return` with an expression in a `void` function, or a `return` without an expression in a non-`void` function.

Comment: @KeithThompson: one distinctly possible reason for C90 allowing a return without an expression in a function returning a value is that pre-standard functions might be `func(x, y) { if (x < y) return; ...do things with x and y...; }`, which is implicitly a function returning an `int` but effectively returning nothing.  This could be outlawed in C99 along with the implicit `int` return type and the implicit `int` type for the parameters to the function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C++11(ISO/IEC 14882:2011) §6.6.3 *The return statement*

> A return statement without an expression can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type void, a constructor, or a destructor. A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value

C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §6.8.6.4 *The return statement*

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

However, C89/C90 only constraints on half of it:

C89/C90(ISO/IEC 9899:1990) §3.6.6.4 *The return statement*

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void .

In the C11 *Forward* section, it lists all the major changes in the third(i.e, C11) and second edition(i.e, C99). The last one of them is:

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> ...
>
> — return without expression not permitted in function that returns a value (and vice
> versa)

This means that the constraint change of function return type is changed since C99.

Comment: What is expression of non-void type?

Comment: That would be like your `void test() {return 1;}` case

Comment: You are allowed to do `return (void)1;` in C++.

Comment: @jxh: Yes, but it's a silly thing to do; just use `return;` with no expression. If the expression has side effects, write it as a statement preceding the `return;`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It is silly the way I wrote it, but it is useful for template functions that return the call of another function (or functor) that is passed as a parameter, and the return type of the template function is a template parameter.

Comment: The C90 standard only has half of that; it says: "A **return** statement with an expression shall not appear
in a function whose return type is **void**." That does cover the code in the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson Interesting to know, I look it up and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Void returns nothing so its obvious compiler won't do anything. If you want to return a value you must define the type whether int ,pointer node etc. etc.

Comment: What's "obvious" about what a C or C++ compiler will do is not always correct. You have to read the language standard if you want to know the actual rules.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement without an expression is the correct way to return from a function that returns void.

But, if you want to provide an expression in the return statement, then you should consider:

```
return (void)(expr);
```

Here, the `expr` is any expression that you want to include to have `side-effects`. As a suggestion, if you want to place a statement for its side-effect, then you should place it before the return statement as :

```
expr;
return;
```